# Special symbols in URLs

Tags: http, url, hyperlink, dns, urlencode

I've just come across this URL for AngelList - http://✌.com/. It's got a weird symbol in it and it redirects to https://angel.co/. Anyone know how this works? I didn't think you could use symbols like this in URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non ASCII symbols (UTF-8) are converted to Punycode (see bellow), so [http://✌.com/](http://xn--7bi.com/) is converted (encoded) to [http://xn--7bi.com/](http://XN--7BI.com/). Owner of this domain set redirection (status of response is 301 Moved Permanently), so you land to https://angel.co/.

> Punycode is a encoding syntax by which a Unicode (UTF-8) string of
> characters can be translated into the basic ASCII-characters permitted
> in network host names. Punycode is used for internationalized domain
> names, in short IDN or IDNA (Internationalizing Domain Names in
> Applications).
>
> For example, when you would type café.com in your browser, your
> browser (which is the IDNA-enabled application) first converts the
> string to punycode "xn--caf-dma.com", because the character 'é' is not
> allowed in regular domain names. Punycode domains won't work in older
> browsers.

[(source of quotation and Punycode encoder/decoder)](http://www.charset.org/punycode.php)

This conversion is described in [RFC 3490](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3490).

Comment: Wow - thanks for the info. Each symbol translates into a different domain. So, it's totally down to whoever happens to own the domain. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It's uncommon, but not impossible. The browser or client URL-Encodes (also called percent encoding) the URL before sending it, so that special characters are transferred properly.

You can read more about URL's here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986